# SimpleXML inserting new line

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

Have this `sample.xml`:

```
<FacturacionAR>
  <Factura xsi:type="FacturaAR">
    <TipoNota>Boleta de Ventas y Servicios</TipoNota>
    <Agencia>LUIL</Agencia>
    <NroFactura>5040</NroFactura>
    <Cliente>JOHAO SMITH CART</Cliente>
    <Ciudad>NUNORK</Ciudad>
    <Direccion>CALLE VITAL DE MELLO</Direccion>
    <Barrio>JAJJKIU</Barrio>
    <Estado>Cancelada</Estado>  
  </Factura>
</FacturacionAR>
```

I want to add "Telefono" every time this node is missing, just after "Barrio", so I tried to do in php:

```
$filename = "sample.xml";

$FacturacionAR = simplexml_load_file($filename,null,true);

 function simplexml_insert_after(SimpleXMLElement $sxe, SimpleXMLElement $insert, SimpleXMLElement $target)
 {
     $target_dom = dom_import_simplexml($target);
     $target_dom->formatOutput = true;
      $target_dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
     $insert_dom = $target_dom->ownerDocument->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($insert), true);
     if ($target_dom->nextSibling) {
          $result = $target_dom->parentNode->insertBefore($insert_dom, $target_dom->nextSibling);
          $target_dom->parentNode->insertBefore($target_dom->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n"), $result);
          return $result;
     } else {
          return $target_dom->parentNode->appendChild($insert_dom);
     }
 }

foreach ($FacturacionAR->Factura as $Factura) {

    if (!isset($Factura->Telefono)) {
                        $meta2 = new SimpleXMLElement("<Telefono/>");
                        $target = current($FacturacionAR->xpath('//Barrio[last()]'));
                        simplexml_insert_after($FacturacionLocalizaAR, $meta2, $target);
    }

}
```

The expected result is:

```
  <Barrio>JAJJKIU</Barrio>
  <Telefono></Telefono>
```

But when I run the php script, this error appears:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 3 passed to simplexml_insert_after() must be an instance of SimpleXMLElement, boolean given
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't show the generation of `$target` but the error is saying that $target has to be a simpleXMLElement and not a boolean var.

Comment: $target is the last node Barrio $target = current($FacturacionAR->xpath('//Barrio[last()]'));, maybe there is the error

Comment: You are most likely using an outdated PHP version. Also you miss to enable error reporting to the highest level. PHP tells you already earlier where your problem is. Your issue is that `current()` returns a boolean, that is the case with some PHP versions only: http://3v4l.org/g69GQ - A proper PHP version will return `NULL` here. Also you should see warnings all over the place, so enable error reporting and set the reporting to the highest level.

Comment: Hi hakre, I'm using php 5.3.1, and the var_dump in current return NULL, just tested. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Upgrading to PHP 5.5.3 solved my problem.